# Angular reactive form with nested array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a complex nested array and I have the data in a object with nested array. I want to display all the data in edit view. I tried it in stackblitz and have issues in loading data . The link is [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kymcqj)

I want to load second level array (groups) in the form text box.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell what exactly is your problem? What you are not getting?

Comment: I want to load second level array (groups) in the form text box.

Comment: Your problem is that your t variable is not the json, you are reading the forms controls and after, you are doing: "t['groups']" t is a formControl, it's not your json, you are doing a strange thing there xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to create `getters` and in some cases, methods that return `FormArray`s.

Here's how:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any[];
  form: FormGroup;

  get tasks() {
    return ( < FormArray > this.form.get('tasks')).controls;
  }

  getGroupsFor(index) {
    return ( < FormArray > ( < FormArray > this.form.get('tasks')).controls[index].get('groups')).controls;
  }

  getDictionaryFor(index) {
    return ( < FormArray > ( < FormArray > this.form.get('tasks')).controls[index].get('dictionary')).controls;
  }

  getAttributesFor(taskIndex, groupIndex) {
    return ( < FormArray > ( < FormArray > ( < FormArray > this.form.get('tasks')).controls[taskIndex].get('groups')).controls[groupIndex].get('attributes')).controls;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      lessoncode: 'TMM',
      countrycode: 'CA',
      languagecode: 'en',
      tasks: this.fb.array(this.getTasks())
    });
    console.log('Form Value', this.form.value);
  }

  getTasks() {
    return this.data.map(task => this.fb.group({
      taskid: task.taskid,
      taskname: task.taskname,
      groups: this.fb.array(this.getGroups(task.groups)),
      dictionary: this.fb.array(this.getDictionaries(task.dictionary))
    }));
  }

  getDictionaries(dictionaries: any[]) {
    return dictionaries.map(dictionary => this.fb.group({
      content_id: dictionary.content_id,
      term: dictionary.term,
      translation_id: dictionary.translation_id,
      value: dictionary.value,
      task_id: dictionary.task_id,
      task_dictionary_id: dictionary.task_dictionary_id,
      isnew: dictionary.isnew,
      altered: dictionary.altered
    }));
  }

  getGroups(groups: any[]) {
    return groups.map(group => this.fb.group({
      id: group.id,
      name: group.name,
      attributes: this.fb.array(this.getAttributes(group.attributes))
    }));
  }

  getAttributes(attributes: any[]) {
    return attributes.map(attribute => this.fb.group({
      name: attribute.name,
      contentid: attribute.contentid,
      value: attribute.value,
      translationvalue: attribute.translationvalue,
      placeholder: attribute.placeholder,
      label: attribute.label,
      defaultvalue: attribute.defaultvalue,
      type: attribute.type,
      element: attribute.element,
      altered: attribute.altered,
      translation_id: attribute.translation_id,
      isnew: attribute.isnew
    }));
  }

  loadData() {
    this.data = [{
        "taskid": 31,
        "taskname": "intro",
        "groups": [{
          "id": 223,
          "name": "Fullscreen Image and Sub-Heading",
          "attributes": [{
              "name": "Main Heading",
              "contentid": 767,
              "value": "Multitasking",
              "translationvalue": "Realización de varias tareas al mismo tiempo",
              "placeholder": "Main Heading",
              "label": "Main Heading",
              "defaultvalue": "",
              "type": "text",
              "element": "input",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": 3063,
              "isnew": false
            },
            {
              "name": "Sub-Heading",
              "contentid": 155,
              "value": "Driver Attitude",
              "translationvalue": "Actitud del conductor",
              "placeholder": "Type Heading",
              "label": "Sub-Heading",
              "defaultvalue": "",
              "type": "text",
              "element": "input",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": 3064,
              "isnew": false
            },
            {
              "name": "Full-Screen Image",
              "contentid": 211,
              "value": "/media/lessons/dst/intro/image01-right.jpg",
              "translationvalue": null,
              "placeholder": "Image Url",
              "label": "Full-Screen Image",
              "defaultvalue": "",
              "type": "image",
              "element": "input",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": null,
              "isnew": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Full-Screen Image",
              "contentid": 212,
              "value": "/media/lessons/dst/intro/image01-left.jpg",
              "translationvalue": null,
              "placeholder": "Image Url",
              "label": "Full-Screen Image",
              "defaultvalue": "",
              "type": "image",
              "element": "input",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": null,
              "isnew": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Full-Screen Image",
              "contentid": 213,
              "value": "/media/lessons/dst/intro/image01-right.jpg",
              "translationvalue": null,
              "placeholder": "Image Url",
              "label": "Full-Screen Image",
              "defaultvalue": "",
              "type": "image",
              "element": "input",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": null,
              "isnew": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Full-Screen Image Alt",
              "contentid": 880,
              "value": "Multitasking - Driver Attitude",
              "translationvalue": "Multitasking - Driver Attitude",
              "placeholder": "Full-Screen Image Alt",
              "label": "Full-Screen Image Alt",
              "defaultvalue": "",
              "type": "alt",
              "element": "input",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": 3062,
              "isnew": false
            },
            {
              "name": "Icon SVG Data",
              "contentid": 3063,
              "value": "",
              "translationvalue": null,
              "placeholder": "SVG Data",
              "label": "Icon SVG Data",
              "defaultvalue": "",
              "type": "html",
              "element": "textarea",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": null,
              "isnew": true
            }
          ]
        }],
        "dictionary": [{
          "content_id": 5,
          "term": "Continue",
          "translation_id": 3065,
          "value": "Continuar",
          "task_id": 31,
          "task_dictionary_id": 11,
          "isnew": 0,
          "altered": 0
        }]
      },
      {
        "taskid": 32,
        "taskname": "question-1",
        "groups": [{
          "id": 228,
          "name": "Question",
          "attributes": [{
              "name": "Question Text",
              "contentid": 956,
              "value": "Welcome to the Multitasking exercise. Before we begin, please select the statement that best describes your current view on the subject.",
              "translationvalue": "Bienvenido al ejercicio sobre realización de varias tareas al mismo tiempo. Antes de comenzar, seleccione la afirmación que mejor describa su opinión actual sobre el tema.",
              "placeholder": "Question Text",
              "label": "Question Text",
              "defaultvalue": "",
              "type": "textarea",
              "element": "textarea",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": 3462,
              "isnew": false
            },
            {
              "name": "Randomize Answers",
              "contentid": 1100,
              "value": "1",
              "translationvalue": null,
              "placeholder": "Randomize Answers",
              "label": "Randomize Answers",
              "defaultvalue": "2",
              "type": "truefalse",
              "element": "select",
              "altered": false,
              "translation_id": null,
              "isnew": true
            }
          ]
        }],
        "dictionary": []
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

And this is going to be your Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="lessoncode" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="countrycode" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="languagecode" />

  <div formArrayName="tasks">
    <div *ngFor="let task of tasks;let taskIndex=index;">
      <h1>Tasks</h1>
      <div [formGroupName]="taskIndex">
        <input formControlName="taskid" />
        <input formControlName="taskname" />
        <div formArrayName="groups">
          <div *ngFor="let group of getGroupsFor(taskIndex);let groupIndex=index;">
            <h2>Group</h2>
            <div [formGroupName]="groupIndex">
              <input formControlName="id" />
              <input formControlName="name" />
              <div formArrayName="attributes">
                <div *ngFor="let attribute of getAttributesFor(taskIndex, groupIndex);let attributeIndex=index;">
                  <h3>Attribute</h3>
                  <div [formGroupName]="attributeIndex">
                    <input formControlName="name" />
                    <input formControlName="contentid" />
                    <input formControlName="value" />
                    <input formControlName="translationvalue" />
                    <input formControlName="placeholder" />
                    <input formControlName="label" />
                    <input formControlName="defaultvalue" />
                    <input formControlName="type" />
                    <input formControlName="element" />
                    <input formControlName="altered" />
                    <input formControlName="translation_id" />
                    <input formControlName="isnew" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div formArrayName="dictionary">
          <div *ngFor="let dict of getDictionaryFor(taskIndex); let dictIndex=index;">
            <h2>Dictionary</h2>
            <div [formGroupName]="dictIndex">
              <input formControlName="content_id" />
              <input formControlName="term" />
              <input formControlName="translation_id" />
              <input formControlName="value" />
              <input formControlName="task_id" />
              <input formControlName="task_dictionary_id" />
              <input formControlName="isnew" />
              <input formControlName="altered" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I've literally spent about an hour creating this for you. But this was fun. **[Here's a StackBlitz for your referece](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-complex-reactive-form)**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for your help and happy then you had fun :) I learnt the advanced Technic from your code... thanks again.

Comment: I optimized the code (single component to multiple child components) .Here is the link . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-forms-reactive?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: You might want to fork it first and then post it. This was just to give you some idea of how to do it in a single component.